# How to Set Initial Value of Angular 2 Reactive Select

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a select list which I want to intialise to a saved value returned from the server. But whatever I try I cannot get it to use the selected value.

I am using Angular **2.2.0** and **Reactive Forms**.

**Here is list of values for the select list.**

```
private categoryList: ICategory[] = [
    new Category({ id: 1, name: 'Cat 1' }),
    new Category({ id: 2, name: 'Cat 2' }),
    new Category({ id: 3, name: 'cat 3' })
];
```

**The saved value is:**

```
{ id: 1, name: 'Cat 1' }
```

**Using FormBuilder I create the form**

```
   this.itemForm = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.required],
      description: [null, Validators.required],
      weight: [null, Validators.required],
      dimensions: [null, Validators.required],
      category:  [null, Validators.required] 
    });
```

**I then initialise it with the saved data**

```
  (<FormGroup>this.itemForm)
        .setValue({
          name: item.name,
          description: item.description,
          weight: item.weight,
          dimensions: item.dimensions,
          category: item.category 
        }, { onlySelf: true });
```

**The template looks like this**

```
<select name="category" [formControl]="itemForm.controls['category']">
         <option [selected]="itemForm.controls['category'].value == null" value="">-- Select --</option>
        <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat">  
            {{cat.name}}
        </option>
    </select>
{{itemForm.controls['category'].value | json }}
```

**Expected Result**
The name of item one is selected in the select and matches the text in the JSON displayed under template

**Actual Behaviour**
The JSON shows this:

```
 { "id": 1, "name": "Cat 1" }
```

But nothing is selected in the select

If --Select-- is chosen the JSON updates correctly to "".

If another cat is chosen, the JSON also updates correctly.

> What am I doing wrong, how do initialise the select?

EDIT
I also tried this:

```
<option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [selected]="itemForm.controls['category'].value.id == cat.id" [ngValue]="cat">
```

Comment: Not knowing if you'll actually get a notification for my answer, since I deleted it and undeleted it. If not, so look below for an answer, which hopefully helps you! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to set an default value. Then you could just refer to your `item.category` + the index of the value you want to set.

I would set the values like this, where we set the first item as a default value.

```
setValues() {
    this.itemForm
        .setValue({
            name: item.name,
            category: item.category[0].id
        })
}
```

and then use `formGroup` and `formControlName` in the form, so:

```
<form [formGroup]="itemForm">
  <input formControlName="name"/>
  <small *ngIf="!itemForm.controls.name.valid">Name is required!</small>
  <!-- More code -->
  <select formControlName="category">
    <! -- set ngValue to cat.id --> instead of just cat!
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat.id">  
      {{cat.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Set the `[ngValue]` (or use just `[value]`) to either `cat.name` or `cat.id` depending on what you want to use, so if you are using `ngValue`, that doesn't bind the whole object!

**Here is a working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Vi2IYF81XkQnW21WJeqp?p=preview)**. Not knowing where you set the values, at which point, I have made a `setValues`-button in the plunker that mimics if the values are set later.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thought I had tried this permutation but it may have got lost as the actual code is a little more complex than this. Thanks for putting me in the right direction though!

Comment: Key for me was the formControlName="name" Im building a dynamic form, so for me it was formControlName="{{name}}"

Answer (score 0):

Try using [attr.selected] and [attr.value] instead of [selected] and [ngValue].

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It is working Angular 5

```
<select formControlName="category">
 <option [ngValue]="undefined" selected disabled>Select Type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let cat of categories" [ngValue]="cat.id">  
      {{cat.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
```